# How to understand the limit placed on integration variable when doing trig substitution?

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

For the calculation of  $\int \frac{1}{x^2-1}{d}x$,  trig substitution method  is to set $\sec\theta=x$.Doing this,  a limit is placed on  x$\in(-\infty,-1]\cup  [1, +\infty) $ . The integration result is $\frac{1}{2}$ $ln|\frac{x-1}{ x+1}$|+C with domain x$\in(-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,1)\cup (1, +\infty) $  , different from the x$\in(-\infty,-1]\cup  [1, +\infty) $.

Another example, if   same trig substitution $\sec\theta=x$ is used to calculate $\int (x^2-1){d}x$, the result is $\frac{1}{3}x^3-x+C$. In this case, the domain of the resulting function is $(-\infty,+\infty)$, again different from x$\in(-\infty,-1]\cup  [1, +\infty) $.

Here is my question, why are we allowed to do the trig substitution in these cases without any special cautions? It does not seem to cause any problems, but why?

Comment: This is not answering your question but you can solve it by subbing $x=iu$ very easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the plots of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-1}$ in blue and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \log |\frac{x-1}{x+1}|$ in orange.

[image]

Notice that $f$ is discontinuous at $|x| = 1$, thus the antiderivative $g$ is also discontinuous there.  The apparent continuity in the picture is a plotting artifact; in actuality, the portion of the curve on $|x| < 1$ is not connected to either of the curves in the regions $x > 1$ or $x < -1$.

Also notice that $g$ is well defined on the set $|x| \ne 1$, not just $|x| > 1$ as you suggest as a result of the substitution $x = \sec \theta$.  Why should this even work?  After all, if $|x| < 1$, there is no real-valued angle such that $\sec \theta = x$.  And while this is correct, what it doesn't acknowledge is that when $|x| < 1$, we could also choose the substitution $$x = \cos \varphi, \quad dx = -\sin \varphi \, d\varphi,$$ hence $$\int f(x) \, dx = \int -\frac{1}{1 - \cos^2 \varphi} \cdot (-\sin \varphi) \, d\varphi = \int \csc \varphi \, d\varphi.$$  And this is the same result as if we used the substitution $x = \sec \theta$ when $|x| > 1$.  One substitution (cosine) handles the $|x| < 1$ case, and the other (secant) handles the $|x| > 1$ case.  Or if you want to do away with trigonometric substitutions entirely, we would simply observe
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1} \right),$$ hence $$\int f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \left( \int \frac{dx}{x-1} - \int \frac{dx}{x+1} \right) = \frac{\log |x-1| - \log |x + 1|}{2} + C = \frac{1}{2} \log \left| \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right| + C.$$

The key insight here is to keep track of any points of discontinuity of the integrand, how these are mapped under substitution, and what happens after the substitution is undone.  In the other case, where we have no discontinuities, we can also use either substitution and again we recover the same antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks for a clear and thorough answer! It makes sense now. Most textbooks do not touch these fine points as you elaborated  so well.